# Tarefa cron não é executada

Tags: php, servidor, backup, cron

Tenho uma tarefa cron que chama uma url, essa url é uma pasta que contém um arquivo index.php. Esse arquivo PHP roda a cada 12 horas e salva os bancos de dados do meu servidor em arquivos .sql dentro de uma pasta, só que pela tarefa cron ele não está fazendo isso, mas se eu chamar essa url direto no navegador, o arquivo PHP é chamado e o backup é feito. Segue código PHP que usei:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$query = "SHOW DATABASES";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $DATABASE = $r['Database'];

    $pasta = date("d-m-Y-H");
    $nome_arquivo = $DATABASE.'.sql';

    $DBUSER="root";
    $DBPASSWD="senha";
    $DATABASE=$DATABASE;
    @mkdir($pasta, 0700);
    $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE > $pasta/$nome_arquivo";

    exec($cmd);
}
```

Essa é a tarefa cron:
curl -s -o /dev/null [http://domínio/bkpserver](http://dom%C3%ADnio/bkpserver)

Comment: já tentou só rodar o curl? Digo, sem usar o navegador, só a linha mesmo. Vê se está respondendo alguma coisa.

Comment: Copie seu comando cmd e rode via bash script se executar corretamente faça o seguinte diminua o tempo de execução do script no cron para rodar de 5 em 5 minutos e com o terminal aberto execute "tail -fn 10 /var/log/cron" aguarde o cron rodar a rotina e pegue o erro, em seguida concerte ou poste aqui para descobrirmos o que é.

Comment: já tentou mudar a permissão para 0777?

Comment: @Daniel, sim, já rodei só o comando mysqldump e ele funcionou sem problemas. Solange, a pasta e o arquivo está 777. Rafael Salomão, tentei executar esse comando, mas disse que não encontrou esse arquivo. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um shell script. Dentro do arquivo Shell Script eu configurei a rotina de cópia do BD e executo o arquivo script pela tarefa cron.

O código utilizado para fazer a conexão e salvar o .sql permanece igual, o que muda é a forma como o arquivo é executado.